# functions to get/set values in multidimensional arrays dynamically

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a shoping cart in php and I have a problem with get/set values in multidimentional arrays.
I keep the current order in `$_SESSION['basket']`. It looks like that:

```
[basket] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pid] => 3
                    [name] => Camera
                    [price] => 200.99
                    [quantity] => 1

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pid] => 5
                    [name] => Computer
                    [price] => 320.99
                    [quantity] => 1

                    [extras] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [pid] => 86
                                    [name] => RAM
                                    [price] => 99
                                    [qty] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [pid] => 98
                                    [name] => CD-ROM
                                    [price] => 19.99
                                    [qty] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )
 )
```

Every item is stored as a subarray. I have a function, which checks if a given item exists in the `basket` array and returns the path to it. For example, if I want to check for a product with `id` `98` (CD-Rom), the function returns the following path: `1:extras:1`.

I cant figure out how to use the path if I want to get or a set a value in the array. Is it possible to construct the path to an array key, without the use of `eval()`? I have these functions:

```
 function get_val($array, $path, $key) {
    //some code
    return eval('return '.$array.$path.$key.';');
 }
```

So, `$price = get_val($_SESSION['basket'], $path, 'price')`; should return the price for CD-ROM (19.99)

```
 function set_val($array, $path, $key, $value) {
    //some code
    $str =  eval(''.$array.$path.$key.';');
    $str = $value;
 }
```

`set_val($_SESSION['basket'], $path, 'price', '30');` will set the price for CD-ROM to 30.

Is there a better way for doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go a code I have finetuned some time ago:

```
  function get_val($array,$path) {
    for($i=$array; $key=array_shift($path); $i=$i[$key]) {
      if(!isset($i[$key])) return null;
    }
    return $i;
  }

  function set_val(&$array,$path,$val) {
    for($i=&$array; $key=array_shift($path); $i=&$i[$key]) {
      if(!isset($i[$key])) $i[$key] = array();
    }
    $i = $val;
  }
```

See this test example, I believe it is what you are looking for:

```
  $data = array("x"=>array("y"=>array("z"=>"foo")));
  echo get_val($data,array("x","y","z")); // foo
  set_val($data,array("x","y","u"),"bar"); // $data["x"]["y"]["u"] = "bar";
```

Comment: ...but if you use also zero keys, you should better use `($key=array_shift($path))!==null` instead

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday people down voted me because I got this function. And today I hope someone can use it.

**Getting values**

Below function will return the value of the path you define.

```
function getPath($path, $array)
{
    $path = split(":", $path);
    $active = $array;
    foreach($path as $key => $part)
    {
        $active = $active[$part];
    }
    return $active;
}

$array = array(array(array(array("product" => array( "id" => 12 )))));

// Give the path to the data you want, by keys
echo getPath("0:0:0:product:id", $array);
```

Which echo's

```
12
```

**And setting values**

```
function setPath($path, &$array, $mykey, $value)
{
    $path = split(":", $path);
    $active =& $array;
    foreach($path as $key => $part)
    {
        $active =& $active[$part];
    }
    $active[$mykey] = $value;

    return $active;
}

$array = array(array(array(array("product" => array( "id" => 12 )))));

// Give the path to the data you want, by keys
 setPath("0:0:0:product", $array, "price", 100);
 print_r($array);
```

Results:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [product] => Array ( [id] => 12 [price] => 100 ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea. I'll try it.

Comment: I have already tested this, so it should be working, if not, just let me know